# Making align produce the same output as multiple aligns

Tags: align

How can I make the following code:

```
\begin{align*}
P(a<\mu<b|\mathbf{y})  = 0.95 \\
P\left(-t_{0.025}<\frac{\mu-\overline{y}}{\widehat{\sigma} / \sqrt{n}}<t_{0.025} |\mathbf{y}\right)  = 0.95 \\
P\left(-t_{0.025}\frac{\widehat{\sigma}}{\sqrt{n}}+\overline{y} < \mu < t_{0.025}\frac{\widehat{\sigma}}{\sqrt{n}}+\overline{y}\right)  = 0.95
\end{align*}
```

...produce the same output as the following code:

```
\begin{align*}
P(a<\mu<b|\mathbf{y})  = 0.95
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
P\left(-t_{0.025}<\frac{\mu-\overline{y}}{\widehat{\sigma} / \sqrt{n}}<t_{0.025} |\mathbf{y}\right)  = 0.95
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
P\left(-t_{0.025}\frac{\widehat{\sigma}}{\sqrt{n}}+\overline{y} < \mu < t_{0.025}\frac{\widehat{\sigma}}{\sqrt{n}}+\overline{y}\right)  = 0.95
\end{align*}
```

The output of the second code has too much white vertical space between each line, however the alignment is what I want, but I am not sure how to achieve that in the first code.

Thanks.

Comment: You have no alignment points (`&`) at all so `align` isn't an appropriate environment, perhaps you want `multline`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the environment `gather*` instead of `align*`.

(`gather`requires `amsmath`, but so does `align`.)

the user documentation for `amsmath` (`texdoc amsldoc`) offers other possibilities as well.